# select tag in HTML

Tags: html

I am trying to achieve following using following code

```
<tr>
 <td width="2%"/>
  <td>[mc "Always Make List"]</td>
   <td>
    <select id="AML" NAME="ALWAYS_MAKE_LIST" style="margin-left:10px;" onchange="OnChange()">
    <option value="Y">Y</option>
    <option value="N">N</option>
    </select>
 </td>
</tr>
```

I am getting extra space in the dropdown list. I need to set default value of first element in dropdown to "Y"

Comment: do you mean `<option value="Y" selected>`?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I think with your code, the default should still be Y because it is the first element

Answer (score 2):

Change the Y option line to `<option value="Y" selected="selected">Y</option>`

Answer (score 2):

Set selected="selected" for the default option.

```
<option value="Y" selected="selected">Y</option>
```

Comment: I tried your code and no blank option. Which browser are you using to view the page? Is there anything else on the page that could effect it such as some javascript.

Comment: I tested on internet explorer 8